# Exporting GeoJSON from QGIS to Mapbox Studio

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geojson, export, mapbox-studio

I am willing to create GeoJSON layer with QGIS, download it and upload it to Mapbox Studio. When I upload the GeoJSON file to Mapbox Studio, I get the following error:

> Input failed. Datasets don't support features outside longitude
> +/-180, latitude +/-90.

This is how I create the GeoJSON File:

- Create new Point shape layer
- Add Features
- Set CRS to Pseudo Mercator EPSG:3857
- Save Layer as GeoJSON

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

The current GeoJSON specification https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946 does not support any other coordinate systems than this one:

> "geographic coordinate reference system, using the World Geodetic
> System 1984 (WGS 84) [WGS84] datum, with longitude and latitude units
> of decimal degrees".

Software developed by MapBox is strict with this requirement. Save your data from QGIS as EPSG:4326.

Many software,like QGIS and GDAL continue to support the 2008 GeoJSON specification http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html that does support different coordinate systems.